# Is it possible to Call one Event into Another Evevnt in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I want to call One Event into Another Event... can we do this task...

```
protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
        DetailsView1.DataSource = GetDetails.GetEmpDetailsById(Convert.ToInt32(Session["empId"]));
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }



protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I just want to Call a `DetailsView1_ModeChanging` Event into a `btnEdit_Click` just Like below

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e);
    }
```

If it is possible Above One how can pass sender and e

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is very ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the logic from `DetailsView1_ModeChanging` into another method, e.g.

```
private void ChangeDataSourceMode(DetailsViewMode newMode) {
    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(newMode);
    DetailsView1.DataSource = GetDetails.GetEmpDetailsById(Convert.ToInt32(Session["empId"]));
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}

protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e) {
    ChangeDataSourceMode(e.NewMode);
}

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangeDataSourceMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
}
```

It's normally not good form to put logic into your event handlers, especially if you plan to reuse the functionality later on, because it limits you to only using the logic in one place.

Answer (score 2):

simple write your event name and paas sender,e like this

DetailsView1_ModeChanging(sender,e);

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to Refactor the logic present in `DetailsView1_ModeChanging` to a private method and invoke the new method from both the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that. Extract your event code into new method and call it.

```
private void SetDetailsViewSource(DetailsViewMode mode)
{
    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(mode);
    DetailsView1.DataSource = GetDetails.GetEmpDetailsById(Convert.ToInt32(Session["empId"]));
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

adn then call it from both events:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    SetDetailsViewSource(e.NewMode);
}

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetDetailsViewSource(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
}
```

This way it is clearer what is going on in your code. Calling event implicitly is a bad idea all around.